# stick footer position to the bottom(basic html and css)

Tags: html, css

I have seen diiferent solutions to stick the footer to the bottom but cannot figure out where my approach is going wrong. I have the style to the footer as follows :

```
footer { 
left: 0; bottom: 0; position : absolute; width: 100%; height : 40px}
```

Initially, it sticks fine to the bottom of the page. Once I minimize the browser and scroll, it is getting stick somewhere at the middle of the page and stays there even after maximizing the window. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The behaviour is because of `position: absolute`

Comment: thanks for the reply @Smit! So there is no way that we can keep the footer stick to the bottom with the position as absolute? If I use the position as fixed, the footer stays there even if the content is beyond 1 page!

Comment: I think you want to have footer on the bottom of the page if content is not fitting the page. Otherwise it should scroll?

Comment: the footer should be at the bottom of the page even if the content is not as long as the page. If the content is beyond the page, the footer lies at the bottom of the content

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: fixed;` instead of `position: absolute;`. you will also need to add some bottom padding to your `<body>` in order to see full content, the value of this padding should be equal to your `<footer>`'s height.

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

footer {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<footer>this is the footer</footer>
```

Check MDN for more info on the [CSS Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position) property.

Comment: If I use the position as fixed, the footer stays there even if the content in the page is beyond 1 page

Comment: What do you mean by "if the content in the page is beyond 1 page"? Could you explain it a little bit!

Comment: If the page has a content that does not fit in a single page, we got to scroll down through the page. In such case, the footer is staying on top of the content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div#footer{
position:fixed; // important
bottom:0; // important
left:0; // important
width:100%
height:100px;
}
```

Here is a JS Fiddle for example:  https://jsfiddle.net/z72tLemr/

I've added some additional tags and CSS to show how it works.  **The key is the position:fixed; in the footer CSS declaration.**  The key is that position:fixed will place the element relative to the browser window, so as you scroll it will stay in place.

Here is more information on position:  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Hope it helps!

Comment: If I use the position as fixed, the footer stays there even if the content in the page is beyond 1 page

Comment: Can you try setting this:
html, body{ height:100%;  }

Answer (score 0):

Assign position:relative to the container, and then position:absolute; bottom:0; to #footer.

Comment: absolute positioning positions relative to the document body if there are no parents with non-static positioning. If the footer is supposed to be at the bottom of the body, I'm pretty sure you don't need any container with some sort of special positioning.

Comment: if it is relative, the footer goes up if there is not enough content to fill the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the footer to stick to the bottom by creating a wrapper, that use negative margins and padding to subtract the height of the footer...

```
/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  /* Negative indent footer by its height */
  margin: 0 auto -40px;
  /* Pad bottom by footer height */
  padding: 20px 20px 40px;
}

footer {
  height: 40px;
}
```

[Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/9DvIIpPwwZ)